# Using Jquery and API - ban

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I may have access to a search API that uses JSON based on a URL GET.  They are quick to ban and the appeal process takes a long time.

Now, if I use this from my website through PHP and hit it too many times, I guess it would be easy to ban (just banning a single IP).

On the other hand, if I were to use Jquery to handle the call and returned data...

Then would it still be possible for the API owner to ban my site?  If yes, how?

Does a Jquery api call still give any signal that they came from my site even though its client side (javascript)?

Comment: I think closing this question is a little extreme.  The purpose of avoiding a ban is because I do not know their limits and the appeal process takes a very long if at all (its a listed tech company).  Their is nothing wrong going on here and i'm surprised by this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, he is being bannable. Ajax is also transfering referer, so with banned referer you would be being unable to access that script. However! You can use any proxy script on free host. LIke this

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://url-of-site-to-retreive-data.com/json.json");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then would it still be possible for the API owner to ban my site?

No, not if you don't supply anything else in the query that is unique for your site. Such as access credentials.

And is it morally correct? No

Is it legal? Probably not, i guess that the webservice has some sort of usage-rules

Comment: that's not 100% true. If user has referer http://hissite.com -> banned. Isn't that true?

Comment: Unsure if referrer is transfered in an ajax request. If it is, then yes it could be banned, by banning on referrer level.